# Encrypted email archive with encryption on client, not server

Tags: email, encryption, imap, email-client, pgp

Even though most of my email is coming in un-encrypted, I want to store it on a server somewhere in encrypted form. Is there any solution available that encrypts **on the client** so that a compromised server still does not mean that my emails can be read by others? (encrypted file systems on the server are not sufficient as the decryption key needs to be on the server as well).

A client that PGP encrypts automatically when storing in a folder would do the trick, together with some batch encryption that encrypts my entire existing folder tree. Have not been able to find either.

Any suggestions? (Linux client preferred, but am interested in other platforms as well)

Answer (score -1):

Unless I am missing something you could use EFS.....

You could achieve you emails in to a folder, then encrypt using EFS (remember to backup the certificate)

Totally encrypted, to my knowledge that is the only other option you have sort of encrypting the whole drive with BitLocker or something like that.

Comment: Here's a [similar answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1118849/how-to-encrypt-e-mails-with-s-mime/1135332#1135332). Usable in conjuction with any email client that stores local copies of emails in an MH folder structure